# elixirでリストの[]をつけたままコンソールに出力する方法がわからない

Tags: elixir

elixirを3日前に勉強し始めた者です。
elixirでリストの[]をつけたまま出力する方法が分からず困っています。
コンソールでa = [1, 2]をタイプして[1, 2]と出力するように、関数内で処理したリストデータを[]をつけた状態でコンソールに出力したいです。
例：

```
defmodule Test do
  def func(input1, input2) do
    funcInside(input1, input2) 
  end

  # まず単純に第1引数と第2引数を掛け算して出力する
  defp funcInside(input1, input2) do
    item1 = hd input1
    item2 = hd input2
    result = item1 * item2
    IO.puts "#{outputList}" #　←　出力をどう書けばコンソールにリストのまま表示されるかわからない。 
  end

#例１：
Test.func([1], [2])
#=> [2] ←コンソールに上記プログラムで処理した後のリストを表示したいです。
#例2：
Test.func([[1, 2, [[2]]]], [[3, 2, [[4]]]])
#=> [[3, 4, [[8]]]] ←コンソールに上記プログラムで処理した後のリストを表示したいです。
```

アドバイス頂けましたら幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

再帰とパターンマッチの話なのかなと思います。
公式ドキュメントで該当しそうなのは↓の辺りになりそうです。

- [List](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.13/List.html)
- [Recursion](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/recursion.html)
- [Pattern matching](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/pattern-matching.html)

Elixirについて知っているわけではないのでより良い書き方があるかも知れませんが:

```
defmodule Test do
  def func([], []), do: []
  def func([h1 | t1], [h2 | t2]), do: [func(h1, h2) | func(t1, t2)]
  def func(input1, input2), do: input1 * input2
end

# 例１：
ex1 = Test.func([1], [2])
# => [2] ←コンソールに上記プログラムで処理した後のリストを表示したいです。
IO.inspect(ex1, charlists: :as_lists)

# 例2：
ex2 = Test.func([[1, 2, [[2]]]], [[3, 2, [[4]]]])
# => [[3, 4, [[8]]]] ←コンソールに上記プログラムで処理した後のリストを表示したいです。
IO.inspect(ex2, charlists: :as_lists)
```

([paiza.io](https://paiza.io/projects/oVrtZSEdQ6znBdrW3hbhlw))

---

2つのリスト

```
l1 = [2]
l2 = [3]
```

が在るとき、リストのままだと掛け算

```
l1 * l2
```

できないので、一旦パターンマッチで数値に分解

```
[i1] = l1
[i2] = l2
```

した上で計算し

```
r = i1 * i2
```

てから元に戻す

```
[r]
```

というのが基本の考え方です。

実際の入力値となっているリストは上の例のように要素が1つではなく、また要素がリストだったりもするので、その部分を再帰的に処理している、というのが最初に書いたコードになります。

質問コード中の

```
item1 = hd input1
```

は、回答コード中では

```
[item1|tail] = input1
```

となっています。
(`item1` 以外の部分(`tail`)も使うので)

---

例1についてのみ考えるのであれば、再帰が不要なので、

> 出力をどう書けばコンソールにリストのまま表示されるかわからない。

の部分を

```
IO.inspect([result], charlists: :as_list)
```

とすれば良いでしょう。
(「リストのまま」というわけではなく、分解したリストを再構築しています)

---

(追記: コメントでの質問について)

リストを入力に受けて、一番左の要素(head)とそれ以外の要素のリスト(tail)に分ける、そしてtailを次の入力にする、という再帰処理しています。

このとき、要素数が1のリストを入力に受けると、tailは要素数が0の空リストになります。
この空リストが次の入力になりますが、その時の処理を定義しているのが

```
  def func([], []), do: []
```

の部分になります。

考え方は[こちら](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/recursion.html#reduce-and-map-algorithms)と同じなので、私の説明が分かりにくければそちらも参照してみてください。

Comment: 教えてくださってありがとうございます。
今、def func([], []), do: []の部分の理解に時間がかかっているため、もしできれば教えて頂きたいです。この処理は何をしているのでしょうか？

第1引数と第2引数でリストを受けるのか？と思ってますが、do:[]で何の処理をしているかもはっきりとわかりませんでした。試しに引数をセットして実行してみましたが、この処理までだと出力が出ないため、何が分かってなくて理解できないか分からずに困っています。

Comment: コメントの質問回答ありがとうございます。理解できました。